# How do you convert 5.8 project to 5.9?

Tags: qt

Everytime I upgrade to a new Qt version, it has some problems to convert the project file. For example I upgraded from 5.8. to 5.9.3 and when I open my 5.8 project file I get this error:

```
Could not find qmake spec 'default'.
Error while parsing file /home/niko/saved-niko-home/MyApp/MyApp.pro. Giving up.
Failed to set up kit for Qbs: Could not determine whether Qt is a static build.
Failed to set up kit for Qbs: Could not determine whether Qt is a static build.
```

Why can't Qt convert a simple .pro file from one version to another automatically???? It is just a text file.

Comment: Normally, that should not be a problem. How have you installed the new version? How do you fix this issue manually?

Comment: @m7913d, the problem was, that I renamed my Qt installation from Qt-new to Qt and this doesn't work. Appears that the path is hardcoded somewhere. I hade to rename the directory back to its original name during install.

Answer (score 0):

You should go to `tools/options/Build & run/Qt versions/` and in this part change your qmake location (Manual) to new like `/home/ahmadi/Qt5.9.3/5.9.3/gcc_64/bin/qmake`